# Get links to change based on click

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have developed a set of code that allows for content to be loaded in, without changing pages, however I've got a problem, I need the links to change as well, but they don't.

My code:

[image]

I don't really understand what's going on with it, but if you make any changes, would you mind commenting them on the code please?

Comment: Please post the code instead of using a picture to show it.

Comment: You're approaching this in the wrong way.. You should use AJAX and PushState. That is, if you're talking about URLs.